# ASP.Net 5 Code 415 Unsopported Media Type when routing over NGINX

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx

I have an ASP.Net 5 Application. Everthing workes fine, but when I use NGINX as reverse Proxy I have the problem that when I post something with Postman etc. I get the Error 415 unsopported Media Type. I think that NGINX removes the content-type header, but i don't know how to change that.

My NGINX Configuration

```
    auth_basic "#MyAuth#";
auth_basic_user_file #MyAuthFile#;
server_name #MyServerName#;
location / {
    proxy_pass https://#MyServerIP:MyServerPort#/;

}
location /static/ {
    root /#MyServerDestination#/;
}
```

My Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using app.bauprofiler.de.Repos;
using Bauprofiler.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Bauprofiler.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProjekteController:ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IProjekteRepository _repo;

        public ProjekteController(IProjekteRepository repo)
        {
            _repo = repo;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get(){
            try
            {
                return Ok(_repo.GetProjekte());
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                 return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id){
            try
            {
                Projekt projekt = _repo.GetProjektById(id);
                if(projekt == null){
                    return NotFound();
                }
                return Ok(projekt);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                 return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Projekt projekt){
            try
            {
                if(!ModelState.IsValid){
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);
                }
                Projekt _projekt = _repo.CreateProjekt(projekt);
                return CreatedAtAction("Get",new {id = _projekt.Id}, _projekt);
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id){
            try
            {
                if(_repo.GetProjektById(id) == null){
                    return NotFound();
                }
                _repo.DeleteProjekt(id);
                return NoContent();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                 return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[My Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeyHG.png)

When i remove the https:// it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When I put an HTTPS:// before my URL all works fine, don't know why.

Comment: Can you show the controller code and how to use postman to access it?

Comment: Yes, i did it. But i don't think thats the problem.